# handling large numbers and overflows

Tags: c, algorithm

I am given an array of N elements and I need to find the index P within this array where
sum of values in the rage 0 to P is equal to sum of values in the range P+1 to N-1.

The values of each element in the array can range to -2147483648 to 2147483647 and 
N can be max 10000000.

Given this how do I ensure there is no overflow when adding each values to find the index P ?

Comment: Sounds like `long long` should suffice.

Comment: @jerry-coffin Note the usage of the word **ensure** in the question at the very end, 'ensure' is not normally considered equivalent to _should_.

Comment: @mctylr: I wouldn't bother mentioning it if it wasn't adequate, but: "`long long` *ensures* sufficient range." Does that make you happier?

Comment: re: adequate - Maybe you'd be surprised with numeric related questions from other users. While correct, my concern is that without an explanation, your original comment sounds flippant. But, I'm happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insure no overflow, use `int32_t` and `int64_t`.

The range of values [-2147483648 ... 2147483647] matches the `int32_t` range.  You could also use `int64_t` for this, but an array of 10000000 deserves space considerations.

As the sum of *any* 10,000,000 values does not exceed the range of `int64_t`, perform all your additions using `int64_t`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
size_t foo(const int32_t *value, size_t N) {
  int64_t sum = 0;
  ...
  sum += value[i];
  ...
}
```

---

BTW: Confident that a solution can be had that does not require addition 64-bit addition.
[Edit] Failed to derive simple `int32_t` only solution, but came up with:

```
size_t HalfSum(const int32_t *value, size_t N) {
  // find sum of entire array    
  int64_t ArraySum = 0;
  size_t P;
  for (P = 0; P < N; P++) {
    ArraySum += value[P];
  }

  // compute sum again, stopping when it is half of total
  int64_t PartialSum = 0;
  for (P = 0; P < N; P++) {
    PartialSum += value[P];
    if ((PartialSum * 2) == ArraySum) {
      return P;
    }
  }

  return N;  // No solution (normally P should be 0 ... N-1)
}
```

Comment: Or to math-geek out a little:  ![sum_{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{N} p_{i} \, \text{where} \, p_{i} \in \mathbf{P} = [-2147483648, 2147483647] \, \text{and} \, N \leq 10000000
](http://mathurl.com/lay9okj) then it isn't hard to conclude that max(sum<sub>n</sub>) is 10000000 * 2147483647 = 21474836470000000 or `0x004C 4B3F FF67 6980` so it does fix within `int64_t` from `stdint.h`

Comment: @ mctylr I suspect the reason for 10000000 is to preclude use of 'double'.  (53 bits + sign)

Comment: @mctylr ;-)  Minor geek point: your math checked only _one_ end of the range.  The min is 10000000 * -2147483648, which like your max, needs 53 bits and a sign.

Answer (score 1):

Use 64 bit integers for your calculations. The best type to use is `int64_t` since `long` is no guaranteed to be 64 bits (you have to `#include <stdint.h>` to make it available).

Edit: Pascal Cuoq is right: `long long` does provide the 64-bit guarantee as well and doesn't need an include (it can be longer than 64 bits, though), so it's just the `long` type that you have to avoid if you want to be portable.

Comment: stdint.h was introduced in C99, which at the same time introduced `long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64-bit, does not require a header, and is not optional in the way the types in stdint.h are.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I didn't know about this guarantee, but I'm sure glad it's there. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score -1):

In the worst case scenario, P+1 = N-1.  Since the max value of an ynumber can only be 2147483647 or -2147483647 for any single number, It means that in the worst cases possible, P would be the max or min of long.  In the other cases, P will still be a long integer. Because of this, you should only need to use a long in the worst case scenario (since if your worse case expected outcome is that P is the largest possible number that any single number can be is a long.

To make sure you don't have to use anything larger, pair up negative values with postive ones so that you stay below the overflow of a long.

Imagine we have 3 numbers, a b and c.  If a + b overflows the long datatype, we know that c will not be P.

Now imagine that we have 4 numbers, a, b, c, d such that a + b + c = d (meaning d is P), if a + b would overflow long, it means 
1) c cannot be P 
2) there is a combination of a + b + c such that the data type of long would not need to be overflowed.

For instance, a is max long, b is max long, c is min long, and d is 0, then a + c + b = d would be the correct combination of operations in order to not use a data type larger than long, and we can try a + c because we know c cannot be P since a + b would overflow long > maximum possible value of P.

Comment: I think this is wrong, if the first two values are 2147483647, when you add them you get an overflow if you are using long.

Comment: @Marichyasana: did you read the last part?  If you have two numbers that are going to overflow long, you don't add them since you know items 1 + 2 > the allowed values of P, so you know P cannot be the next item.  As such, there must be values in the future that will bring this number down below the overflow point, and thus you can pair it with a negative number in the future to negate any overflow effect from two numbers. Stop thinking so serially, its a stupid way to think.

Comment: @Magn3s1um There is no reason to believe that there are negative numbers coming which will bring a running sum closer to zero. And I think you misunderstood the question. There is no specified cap on the sum that can be reached. The sum of the lower partition of the array which is equivalent to the sum of the upper partition can be a very large number that overflows 32 bits many, many times over again. All the values in the array could be large, positive integers.

Comment: @Kaz No, i think you misunderstood.  Here's what he said "The values of each element in the array can range to -2147483648 to 2147483647."  Since P is in the array, it means it has a bounds on its size.  Therefore, if there are 3 numbers, a-b-c, if a + b would overflow the range of long, it means that c cannot be P.  Since this is the case, since this addition would overflow, and P needs to be in the range of long, it means there MUST be values which would offset the overflow, or else there would not be a P that exists in the list within that range.  Schooled.

Comment: OP does not mention `long`and C does not oblige `long` to be 32-bit 2's compliment.  OP does not state a limit to the sum of any 2 numbers other than the max array size.  `P` is an _index_.  OP's "sum of values in the rage 0 to P is equal to ..." certainly means "sum of values from array[0] to array[P] is equal to ...".

Comment: P is not in the array. P is an index into the array, whose size is limited to ten million elements.